# Using domain in Odoo colors attribute

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-8

Is it possible to have a domain-like condition in Odoo `colors` attribute instead of a single condition ?

example : I wanna have a condition like this `colors="blue:state=='approved'&&doc_type=='revisi'"`

I noticed that we could have a hidden function field that filled depend on the both fields and use it in the `colors` attribute, but is there the simpler way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can use multiple condition on colors with the help of `and` and `or` for example:

```
colors="blue:state=='approved' and doc_type=='revisi' "

colors="blue:state=='approved' or doc_type=='revisi' "
```

Comment: Yes it works like a charm! Thank you very much. And I also notice to have a condition that compared against empty string, we should use doc_type==False instead of doc_type==''.